# Close JQuery dialog from inside partial

Tags: jquery, dialog, partial

I open a JQuery model dialogue box which displays a form (MVC partial). The partial is very simple, has a few input fields.

I use the <% using (Html.BeginForm.... to post the form to a given action method when the save submit button is clicked.

However, I want to have a cancel button on the form that closes the dialogue when clicked but which doesn't post to the form action.

Is there a way to close the parent dialogue box from with in the partial view? Or can you suggest an alternative approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be something that could help you ?

```
<div>
    <form></form>
</div>

$('div').dialog({
   buttons:{
      save:function (){
          $('div form').serialize();
          //ajax goes here, thats is the intention of jq dialog () :)
      },
      cancel:function (){
         $(this).dialog('close');
      }
   }
});
```

if not then please do post some code to give us a better picture of what you mean

Comment: Thanks Val, I'll give it a go. I thought that I might have to do something similar but wasn't sure of the syntax. I'll let you know how I get on with it. Thanks

Comment: I gave the form an Id, and then could serialize and receive a populated FormCollection in my action method (using a $.post(url...., {"blah" : serialisedData); but I thought going one step further and creating a custom model binder word work. It didn't should it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't finish! @Val, I gave the form an Id, and then could serialize and receive a populated FormCollection in my action method (using a $.post(url...., {"blah" : serialisedData); but I thought going one step further and creating a custom model binder word work. I created a new custom model binder for the type, changed the parameter for the action method to receive the type aligned with the new model binder, but the model binder OnModelUpdated method never fires. I also registered the model binder for the type in the global.asax. Should model binding work with posts from JQUery?

Comment: I have not work on that custome model binder you are mentioning but I am going to have a look at it myself :)